# How does GraphX internally traverse the Graph?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, graph-traversal, spark-graphx

I want to know the internal traversal of Graph by GraphX. Is it vertex and edges based traversal or sequential traversal of RDDS? For example given a vertex of graph, i want to fetch only of its neighbors Not the neighbors of all the vertices ? How GraphX will traverse the graph in this case.

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

> For example given a vertex of graph, i want to fetch only of its
>   neighbors

I think it is not possible because you always apply some operations to the whole RDD, so in this case you should not care how GraphX traverse the graph.